# Voting Closed But Can?

Tags: support, voting, stackegg

StackEgg. A great, fun game for us SE people to enjoy as we wait for something to do here. Weird thing happened to me. When I attempted to vote on StackEgg, it said that the voting round has been closed and I need to wait for the next voting round. I chose an option anyway and my vote was accepted. That was weird.

So I kinda have tow questions here: First, how does the voting round get closed, and secondly, how did just bypassed the supposedly closure of the voting round?

Note: The timer was still on (the 20 seconds were not completely gone) when this happened. Please help! And Happy April Fools Day! (and April Fools Eve!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "the voting round is closed now" time is very short (about half a second), so when you cast your second vote, the *new* voting round was already open.

The timer tries to be as accurately as possible. What it shows you is the number of seconds that it thinks have to elapse until a request has no chance anymore to reach the server in time for the voting round end. For this it has to take into account what (it thinks) the *time offset* between your computer and the server is, and what (it thinks) the *connection latency* between the two is. If that sounds like something that can only be achieved in a best-effort fashion that can't give 100% precision, that's because it is :)